# Can we see deleted posts which we downvoted?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, 10k-tools, deleted-posts

At the moment, we can see, in the activity and flags pages, deleted posts which we have cast close or delete votes, or flags. However, the [list of downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=downvote) doesn't include deleted posts, even if the same post is visible in the closed/deleted/flagged posts' lists. Can we also see deleted posts which we have merely downvoted?

I like to review posts which I have VTC/D'd or flagged, or downvoted, and it's useful to see what happened to them after I acted on them.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot but don't quote me on that. I like to bookmark posts that I want to go back to review later in my browser, I've got a special folder. It works well enough, and is deletion-proof. So that's an alternate option you could consider.

Comment: i belive you can. in your profile under the Reputation tab, at the very bottom there is a checkbox labled "show removed posts". if you have the rep to see deleted posts normally the links there should take you to it

Comment: @Memor-X ah yes, indeed that list does show them. I'd still like it in the downvotes list though, for consistency and ease of reviewing.