# Activity summary page counts votes on deleted posts in vote totals

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, down-votes, deleted-posts

My summary page on Ask Ubuntu says that I have cast 3,173 downvotes. However, on posts that are not deleted I have cast only 1,102 downvotes (since [we can't see deleted posts in the downvotes tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290758/can-we-see-deleted-posts-which-we-downvoted)).

When I saw that my downvote count had become nearly as high as my upvote count, I started to wonder if I'd become too negative ... and then I realised it's counting all the downvotes that I'd cast to activate the delete option on low-quality answers (which I do since otherwise I'd have to see that post in the review queue).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to encourage *down-voting* as well as up-voting.

Voting is a very crucial which is explained at [help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/). There's also [guideline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote) available as a FAQ.

So, If someone visits profile and see that users are primarily casting up-votes only (assume vote casted on deleted post are not counted), then s/he may not encouraged to  cast *vote down* when essential.

*This is actually [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) of a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): **["Votes cast" should include votes on deleted contributions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117846/260388)***

So, when someone visit your profile and found that you're considering up-voting as well as down-voting, s/he may got the idea/guideline on voting like: Up-Vote good contents and Down-Vote bad contents.

In brief, it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) as applied to the question.

Comment: It doesn't encourage downvoting, it encourages keeping a high downvote/upvote ratio.